# setting state twice in a geocodeByAddress function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set state to the trip object based on the return of the geocodeByAddress react-places-autocomplete function. The return of the latitude and the longitude gets mapped to pickup object and the latitude/longtitude params. However, the setState twice does not work. Can anyone see a work-around?

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        trip: {
            pickUp: null,
        },
        pickupLatitudeDisplay: '',
        pickupLongitudeDisplay: '',
}
}
handlePickupSelect = address => {
    const {
        pickupLatitudeDisplay,
        pickupLongitudeDisplay,
    } = this.state;

    geocodeByAddress(address)
        .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
        .then(results => {
            console.log('Success', results)
            this.setState({
                pickupLatitudeDisplay: results.lat,
                pickupLongitudeDisplay: results.lng,
            }, () => {
                this.setState({
                    trip: {
                        ...this.state.trip,
                        pickUp: {
                            ...this.state.trip.pickUp,
                            latitude: pickupLatitudeDisplay,
                            longitude: pickupLongitudeDisplay,
                        },
                    }
                })
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));}
```

Comment: `setState` is async method, component should reactive "react" at changes. What you experienced here are so called "side effects". For async methods you should try something like redux-thunk or redux-observable. But at first move state to props, if you don't want to change it to props, you have to "observe" (eg. using rxjs observable) for state changes.

Comment: What's not working? Guess you're getting an error when you try to spread this.state.trip.pickUp cause it's null in the initial state. Set it to an empty object initially instead. 

Also don't follow along quite here as we can't see more of the code. But why are you setting the state two times? You could set it all in one setState call as far as I can see it.